# Set asmselect id while initiating

Tags: jquery, asmselect

Is there any way to set id for asm select instead of having it initiated automatically?
Thank you in advanced.

```
<select multiple id="mySelect">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

$("#mySelect").asmSelect({
    animate: true,
    addItemTarget: 'bottom'
});
```

I don't want the asmSelect id to be "asmSelect0", please show me how to change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this plugin renders an entirely new visual representation of your original select element and then hides it. The id for the new select container is a composition of `options.selectClass + index`. The `selectClass` is hard coded into the plugin and `index` is determined internally. The author left no exposed method to change these variables.

If you want this id to be different you'll need to change the `options` object in the plugin code itself or change the element's id with JavaScript after you call the plugin.

To change the ID afterwards just use the [JQuery .attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#asmSelect0').attr('id', 'newId');
```

Replace `newId` with the id you choose.

Comment: can you show me how to change the element's id with javascript after 
calling this?
$("#mySelect").asmSelect({
    animate: true,
    addItemTarget: 'bottom'
});
thank you